# Qt: Cannot queue arguments of type MyClass

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qthread

I'm trying to pass my Class trough a signal with this:

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(SIG_connectSerial(SerialSetting::Settings)), serial, SLOT(openConnection(SerialSetting::Settings)),Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

The class I want to pass is that class:

```
#ifndef SERIALSETTING_H
#define SERIALSETTING_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QtSerialPort/QSerialPort>



namespace Ui {
class SerialSetting;
}   

class QIntValidator;

class SerialSetting : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    struct  Settings {
            QString portName;
            qint32 baudRate;
    };

    Settings settings();



public:
    explicit SerialSetting(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~SerialSetting();

private slots:
    void apply();

    void on_btnApply_clicked();

private:
    void fillPortsParameters();
    void fillPortsInfo();
    void updateSettings();


private:
    Ui::SerialSetting *ui;
    Settings currentSettings;
    QIntValidator *intValidator;
};

#endif // SERIALSETTING_H

#include "serialsetting.h"
#include "ui_serialsetting.h"

#include <QtSerialPort/QSerialPortInfo>
#include <QIntValidator>
#include <QLineEdit>

QT_USE_NAMESPACE

static const char blankString[] = QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP("SettingsDialog", "N/A");

SerialSetting::SerialSetting(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::SerialSetting)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    intValidator = new QIntValidator(0, 4000000, this);

    //ui->cboBaudRate->setInsertPolicy(QComboBox::NoInsert);

    fillPortsParameters(); //call function to fill comboboxes

    connect(ui->btnApply, SIGNAL(clicked()),this, SLOT(apply()));
}

SerialSetting::~SerialSetting()
{
    delete ui;
}

void SerialSetting::fillPortsParameters()
{

//fill cboComport with all available comports
foreach(const QSerialPortInfo &info, QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts())
    {
    ui->cboComport->addItem(info.portName());
    }

}

void SerialSetting::apply()
{
    SerialSetting::currentSettings.portName = ui->cboComport->currentText();
    hide();
}

SerialSetting::Settings SerialSetting::settings()
{
    return SerialSetting::currentSettings;
}

void SerialSetting::on_btnApply_clicked()
{

}
```

The compiler throws this exception:
QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'SerialSetting::Settings'
(Make sure 'SerialSetting::Settings' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
I tried `qRegisterMetaType<SerialSetting>();` but this ended in the following error:

```
static assertion failed: Type is not registered, please use the Q_DECLARE_METATYPE macro to make it known to Qt's meta-object system
 #define Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X(Condition, Message) static_assert(bool(Condition), Message)
```

Adding the Makro `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Ui::SerialSetting)` at the end of the class-header throws another error:

```
invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'Ui::SerialSetting'
         isLarge = (sizeof(T)>sizeof(void*)),
```

Comment: Do exactly what the error message says!

Comment: And what happened after adding the [`Q_DECLARE_METATYPE`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE) macro Qt's error so helpfully told you to add?

Comment: After adding Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Ui::SerialSetting) at the end of my headerfile of the class the compiler shows this message: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'Ui::SerialSetting'
         isLarge = (sizeof(T)>sizeof(void*)),

Comment: You probably need to add an include. Can you point out what file / line this error is on?

Comment: the compiler says the error occurs in file qtypeinfo.h in line 60..

Comment: The code you posted does not have the `SerialSetting` class in the `Ui` namespace. Something is not right. Please post the actual code that is causing the problem (remember the posted code should be _*minimal*_ too). Also, is all your code in the header? If not logically separate the posted code to show which files have what content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't call `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` on a forward-declared class (`Ui::SerialSetting`). Also, you need to declare the type *that the signal uses as a parameter*, in this case, `SerialSetting::Settings`.

Replace

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Ui::SerialSetting)
```

with

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(SerialSetting::Settings)
```

and you should be fine.